# How to Authenticate Wordpress and PHP Aplication with same credentials?

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

I have two websites, one is Wordpress and other is PHP. How to login Wordpress and my PHP app with the same credentials.

I need that when a user registers on my WordPress site he automatically appears registered on the PHP site.

Comment: Ypu caught me searching how to re-use wordpress database for this :) Still did not find any good results, but that could be the way - use same table for users in your PHP app and in wordpress

Comment: This article seems full featured http://dovy.io/wordpress/authenticating-outside-of-wordpress-on-diff-domain I was looking at `app/web/wp/wp-includes/user.php` and see there's a `wp_signon()` and `wp_authenticate_cookie()` functions. I'd also look at how `wp_authenticate_username_password()` works

Comment: @PavelJanicek Using the same table for both sites not solve my problems,I still looking for answers!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [OAuth 2.0 Server](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) , a package by thephpleague.
It will allow you to turn one of your applications into an oauth-server, the second one being the client.

The oauth-server application would grant an api key to the client so that its users can login from the client application.

The same thing happens when for instance you login to Stackoverflow using your google/facebook account : google/facebook is the server, and stackoverflow the client.

I think using oauth would be cleaner, more secure and standard compliant than duplicating your users datas accross two web apps for the following reasons :

- you would need to replicate each new user on any of your website;
- compromising any of your websites would give the attacker your users credentials(login, password) for the two web apps, whereas with oauth he can't get the passwords of the oauth-server users while being on the client;
- etc;

There are many other reasons but there a more experienced developers able to give you deeper explanations.

There's also a wordpress plugin that would fit your needs that you can find [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) for JSON Web Token Authentication.

Comment: I have researched about OAuth. But I think my approach is a bit different and I do not know if OAuth is my solution. I need that when a user logs in my Wordpress site and wants to access my site in PHP (from the Wordpress site itself) if it is registered in my site in PHP access and appears logged, otherwise do not access the PHP site.

Comment: Did you check the [JSON Web Token plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)  for wordpress ?

Comment: You can also look at this  [list of plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/ldap-single-sign-on/) implementing [single sign on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) with [ldap](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol).

Comment: I already have OAuth2 on my Wordpress site as a server, the problem is that I don´t know how to make my PHP sites the clients to use the credentials of my Wordpress site. I don´t know what to include or add on my PHP sites to make this work.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](https://wp-oauth.com/documentation/how-tos/setup-wp-oauth-server-single-sign/); it shows how to setup a complete authentication mechanism with links to examples projects. Here's the link to example clients from this tutorial if you want to directly go there : https://github.com/justingreerbbi/wordpress-oauth-server-clients